# Could I reflect a commercial laser off of the reflectors left on the moon by the astronauts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, laser

Would an ordinary laser pointer reach the reflectors placed on the moon? I want to reflect a laser off of the moon. How powerful must my laser be?

Comment: Mandatory [xkcd what-if reference](https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/).

Comment: Further to @AndréasSundström's comment, if you bounce a laser off a target a distance $r$ away, not only does it have $r^{-2}$ attenuation at the target, but your detector of the reflection has to contend with another such factor, making $r^{-4}$ overall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure  the lasers used by the agency are strong , and what is important, the detection of the return from the [reflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) difficult even for [the agency:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector#On_the_Moon)

> Even under good viewing conditions, only a single reflected photon is received every few seconds. This makes the job of filtering laser-generated photons from naturally occurring photons challenging.

For sure an ordinary laser cannot work.

Answer (score 1):

The first measurement of the distance to the moon by timing the round-trip flight of laser pulses was done using a 50 Joule ruby laser (avg power during each 500 microsecond pulse was 100 kW) in 1962. That was *before* they put retroreflectors on the lunar surface.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment#History

I'm not 100% certain, because it's hard to find pricing information about lasers in that category without speaking on the phone to a sales consultant, but I'm pretty sure that there are comparable "commercial" lasers.

Obviously, the size of the laser matters, but what also matters is the size of the *telescopes* that you use (one to collimate the outgoing laser beam, and one to catch the reflected light,) and also, the sensitivity of your detector.

Comment: What was pulse repetition rate? Commercial lasers should definitely be available to hit the required specs, but definitely outside the “regular laser pointer” category.